# How to search a String from multiple columns in an Sqlite database and returns the results in listview?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor, android-sqlite

I'm trying to search a String from my database that contains mainly 3 columns (Questions, answers and comments), so the user can search for a word, and any instance of that word in any columns should appear in the search result.
I used this code but it returns only the search from the first column only. have you any idea what's wrong with my code:

```
public Cursor search(String searchString) {

    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_QUESTION,KEY_ANSWER, KEY_COMMENT};
    String where =  KEY_QUESTION + " LIKE ? OR "+ KEY_ANSWER  + " LIKE ? ";
    searchString = "%" + searchString + "%";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[]{searchString};

    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {if (database == null) {
        database = openHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    }

        cursor = database.query(TABLE_FLASH, columns, where, whereArgs, null, null, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SEARCH EXCEPTION! " + e); // Just log the exception
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are providing only one argument but your query has two, so second one will be null.
Try this:

```
String[] whereArgs = new String[]{searchString, searchString};
```

Comment: **Many Thanks Okas**, you make my day. what I understood is that for each column I should add a new 'searchString' in the whereArgs array. Okas do you suggest a specific documentation to in-depth my understanding?